# monic irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$ have a multiple root in $F_p$ over $F_p[x]$ for some prime $p$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

Could you help me with the following problem which I cannot solve ?

> Let $f\in \mathbb Z[x]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial with $deg(f)>1$.
>
> Prove or disprove that there is always a prime $p$ satisfying the following condition:
> $\overline{f}$ have a multiple root in $F_p$
> where $\overline{f}$ is a polynomial in $F_{p}[x]$, whose coefficients are the reduction of those of $f$ modulo $p$.

---

From Minkowski's bound, |disc$(f)|>1$.

So we can take a prime $p$ dividing  |disc$(f)|$.

Then $\overline{f}$  have a multiple root in algebraic closure of $F_p$.

However, this does not mean $\overline{f}$ have a multiple root in $F_p$.

For example, $f=x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 6$ and $p=5$.

In this case, disc$(f)$$=35600$ and $\overline{f}=(x^2+x+1)^2$ over $F_p$.

(On the other hand,$\overline{f}=x^2(x+1)^2$ over $F_2$)

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: First and foremost, please study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). That way your questions can avoid negative attention - something that will improve your experience on the site immensely!

Comment: But I also wonder what has been covered recently in your class? All the more reason that you help us help you by adding such pieces of information to the question body! Have you had any results about discriminants of field extensions and irreducible polynomials?

Comment: i'm sorry for inconvenience. I added comments.

Comment: Good job with the edit! I just voted to "Leave open" in the review queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is actually false.

Consider the polynomial $f=\Phi_{12}=X^4-X^2+1$. It's straightforward to see that $\Phi_{12}$ divides $X^{12}-1$. The latter polynomial is coprime with its derivative in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p > 3$. So we need to check that $\Phi_{12}$ has no double root in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p=2$ and $p=3$.

For $p=2$, $\overline{f}(x) = (x^2+x+1)^2$ so we're done. For $p=3$, $\overline{f}(x)=(x^2+1)^2$ and we're also done.